# SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token when running tests with jest and react testing library

Tags: reactjs, next.js, jestjs, react-testing-library, babel-jest

Counter.test.js:

```
import Counter from 'components/Counter';
import { render, fireEvent } from '@testing-library/react';
import '@testing-library/jest-dom/extend-expect';

describe('Counter Testing', () => {
  it('should pass', () => {
    const { container } = render(<Counter></Counter>);
    expect(container.querySelector('#count-value')).toHaveTextContent('0');
    fireEvent.click(container.querySelector('#decrement-btn'));
    expect(container.querySelector('#count-value')).toHaveTextContent('0');
  });
});
```

Counter.js

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

const Counter = props => {
  const {count, setCount} = useState(0);

  const handleIncrement = () =>{
     count<10 ? setCount(count+1) :null;
  }
  const handleDecrement = () =>{
     count>0 ? setCount(count-1) :null;
  }

  return (
    <div>
      Counter: <span id='count-value'>{count}</span>
      <button onClick={handleIncrement} id='increment-btn'>+1</button>
      <button onClick={handleDecrement} id='decrement-btn'>-1</button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Counter;
```

Here i'm trying to test on clicking decerement button it should not go beyond 0. However i'm continuously returning error. Please find the below screen shot.

[image]

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Do you have a jest.config file? What is inside?

Comment: Show your jest config or provide a codesandbox or github repo link